# Sequelize Model.destory() is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
module.exports = async (_, args, {currentUser, db}) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
        throw new Error('Not authenicated!')
    }
    await db.Fixtures.destory({})
    return true
}
```

I am new to Sequelize, I don't understand why it is telling db.Fixtures is not a function. I have tested findAll in the function to check that I have passed the models through correctly and that works fine.

any help would be appreciated, I am using version 6.4.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a typo. It should be `db.Fixtures.destroy()`, not `db.Fixtures.destory()`.

Comment: Thank you I have been staring at that for ages, knew I gad gone daft

Comment: @Chris If you use VSCode you can get the "CSpell for VSCode" extension which spellchecks your code, it's nice.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but thank you @Logan

Comment: How funny, I had just done this same exact misspelling. Thanks!